# Calculating potential Chess moves

Tags: python, python-3.x, chess

I started a Chess in Python for fun. I learned Python in my free time but I've been doing it for a while. The code works but I just want to know if there's anything non-pythonic in my code. The functions calculate all potentially possible moves (ignoring game state).

```
from itertools import product
from itertools import chain
from functools import wraps
from math import atan2

_angle_to_direction = {90: "up", -90: "down", 180: "right", 0: "left", -135: "right_down", 135: "right_up",
                       45: "left_up", -45: "left_down"}


def move(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        x, y = args
        moves = f(x, y)
        if (x, y) in moves: moves.remove((x, y))
        return moves

    return wrapper


def check_range(x:tuple) -> bool:
    return x[0] >= 0 and x[1] >= 0 and x[0] < 8 and x[1] < 8


@move
def _knight(x:int, y:int) -> set:
    moves = chain(product([x - 1, x + 1], [y - 2, y + 2]), product([x - 2, x + 2], [y - 1, y + 1]))
    moves = {(x, y) for x, y in moves if check_range((x, y))}
    return moves


@move
def _rook(x:int, y:int) -> set:
    return {(x, i) for i in range(0, 8)}.union({(i, y) for i in range(0, 8)})


@move
def _bishop(x:int, y:int) -> set:
    possible = lambda k: [(x + k, y + k), (x + k, y - k), (x - k, y + k), (x - k, y - k)]
    return {j for i in range(1, 8) for j in possible(i) if check_range(j)}


def direction(start:tuple, end:tuple) -> str:
    delta_a = start[1] - end[1]
    delta_b = start[0] - end[0]
    return _angle_to_direction[int(atan2(delta_a, delta_b) * 180 / 3.14)]
```

Comment: Your `check_range()` can be simplified to `min(x)>=0 and max(x) < 8` or (maybe most pythonic) `all(0 <= c < 8 for c in x)`. Also, why remove (x,y) in the wrapper but check_range() individually in each function? Wouldn't it be more logical to do check_range() also in the wrapper? then you may note that the "vector pieces" rook and bishop (and queen which is the union) work in the same way, you could just give a direction (e.g. (1,1)) and add or subtract as long as check_range(). King and knight go just 1 step in each direction (or opposite), pawn is again slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of your `move` decorator is a little schizophrenic. On the one hand, it carefully allows any and all arguments to be passed to it by declaring itself `def wrapper(*args, **kwargs)`. However it then requires exactly two positional arguments which it then passes on to the wrapped function. Keyword arguments are accepted but ignored and dropped. I would suggest changing this to be all at one end or all at the other end of this spectrum. Given the annotations elsewhere, I would expect you to prefer changing the function to `def wrapper(x, y)` (or maybe to `def wrapper(x, y, **kwargs)` but then also passing `**kwargs` to `f`).

It might make sense to incorporate `check_range` into the wrapper as well, simplifying most of the move generators. It might also make sense to skip the decorator and instead call the filter in your move generators: `return filter_move((x, y), moves)`.

As a side note, it would be interesting to see if there are any performance advantages to either the current approach of checking for `(x,y)` and conditionally removing it or to unconditionally doing a set difference: `return f(x, y) - {(x, y)}`.

The rest of your code is fairly straightforward, if perhaps a bit too clever. Clever is typically bad for other readers, or for debugging misbehavior. The two things that stand out to me is the name of your lambda `possible` (which seems more like a `diagonal_moves_of_distance` or simply `diagonal`), and the approach used for `direction`. Given the limited number of possible move deltas, bringing in trigonometry to handle it seems like overkill; I'd almost expect a simple if/else tree instead. As is, it will have problems classifying a knight's move.

Comment: thank you sir. i would agree with you being too clever is bad that was my main concern. very detailed answer much appreciated